# Ruby spreadsheet : getting column count in xls file

Tags: ruby, excel, spreadsheet, xls

Is there any way to count the number of columns in a spreadsheet file using ruby? I am using the latest version of spreadsheet gem.

Comment: Which "spreadsheet gem" are you using?  There are a number of them.

Comment: there is only one gem with that name...https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet

Comment: Just trying to be clear.  Although there is only 1 gem on rubygems w/ that specific name, there are a number of spreadsheet gems.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages and "[mcve]" along with “[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)”. Your question is premature. We expect to see what you tried, along with an explanation of why it didn't work. You're asking for a tutorial but we don't know what you did toward solving the problem, which'd result in a large answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there are a number of possible solutions based on your needs and situation:

```
book = Spreadsheet.open('/path/to/an/excel-file.xls')
sheet1 = book.worksheet(0)

# get the number of columns in the first row
sheet1.row(0).size

# get the maximum number of columns in all the rows
sheet1.rows.max_by(&:size)

# use the dimension logic from the gem.  It looks like this ignores empty columns at the beginning of the sheet
sheet1.column_count
```

`column_count` source: 
https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet/blob/master/lib/spreadsheet/worksheet.rb#L96-L99

Let us know what works for you and what you find out by playing with it.